# BibTeX Vancouver Style Fields

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I have added the following book entry to the `bibrefs.bib` file which I use for entering the references:

```
@book{3,‎
    author = {Loo, P and Loo, H},‎‎
    title = {Constant Stress},
    translator = {Gharib ‎Abbas},‎
    origlanguage = {English},
    year = {1998}‎,‎‎
    pages = {111--158},
    address = {Tehran},
    publisher={Shine}‎‏‎‎‎
}‎‎
```

test.tex

```
‎\documentclass[12pt]{report}‎‎
‎
\begin{document}‎
\cite{3}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
‎\bibliography{bibrefs‎}

\end{document}
```

I do need to add the "translator" and "pages" fields using the BibTeX; so, I add the `translator` field to explicitly specify the translator's name, but the translator's name doesn't appear in the output file. I'm using the "style of Vancouver" which gets applied to the bibliography by the `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}` statement. According to the style of Vancouver which is available in the Wikipedia and also in its [official website](http://library.vcc.ca/downloads/VCC_VancouverStyleGuide.pdf), you may add the translator and the chapter and the used pages of the referenced book.
But the output I see is the following:

[image]

I mean, the translator which is specified using the `translator` field is not shown. I also add the `pages` field and still not getting that in the output while the bibTeX doesn’t throw any errors, looks like it's syntax is correct but there is not any output correspondence.

So; how may I achieve the desired results?
I appreciate all the helps in advance.

Answer (score 2):

the vancouver bst style does not have a translator field (and bibtex by design simply ignores unknown fields, they are not an error) You could attempt to modify it but simpler would be to pick an existing bst file that does support translator.

in my texlive 2016 installation these bst files have "translator" perhaps one of them is suitable for your needs,

```
$ grep -l translator `find . -name \*.bst`
./amsrefs/amsra.bst
./amsrefs/amsrn.bst
./amsrefs/amsrs.bst
./amsrefs/amsru.bst
./amsrefs/amsry.bst
./apacite/apacann.bst
./apacite/apacannx.bst
./apacite/apacite.bst
./apacite/apacitex.bst
./biblatex/biblatex.bst
./bookdb/bookdb.bst
./cquthesis/cqunumerical.bst
./frankenstein/achicago.bst
./jurabib/jox.bst
./jurabib/jurabib.bst
./jurabib/jureco.bst
./jurabib/jurunsrt.bst
./persian-bib/acm-fa.bst
./persian-bib/asa-fa.bst
./persian-bib/chicago-fa.bst
./persian-bib/ieeetr-fa.bst
./persian-bib/plain-fa-inLTR-beamer.bst
./persian-bib/plain-fa-inLTR.bst
./persian-bib/plain-fa.bst
./persian-bib/plainnat-fa.bst
./persian-bib/unsrt-fa.bst
./seuthesis/seuthesis.bst
./seuthesix/seuthesix.bst
./uestcthesis/uestcthesis.bst
```